# function to render multiple arrays into a table creates empty td tags

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm combining arrays to output their data inside a table.
The combining goes successful so far.. but after that I think some things went wrong. The solution must be really simple though, but at this point I can't figure it out... it seems after each loop from the map function there are empty td tags created that push the rows down.

testdata:

```
export const arr1 = [{
  "tre": 1,
  "tro": "Nikkie"
}, {
  "tre": 2,
  "tro": "Donia"
}, {
  "tre": 3,
  "tro": "Lavena"
}];

export const arr2 = [{
  "bla": 1,
  "blo": "Carola"
}, {
  "bla": 2,
  "blo": "Rosa"
}, {
  "bla": 3,
  "blo": "Geneva"
}];

export const arr3 = [{
  "bra": 1,
  "bru": "Currie"
}, {
  "bra": 2,
  "bru": "Aura"
}, {
  "bra": 3,
  "bru": "Irwinn"
}];
```

Function:

```
tableData() {
    const combined = [...arr1, ...arr2, ...arr3];

    var data = combined.map((i, k) => {
      return (
        <tr key={k}>
          <td>{i.tre}</td>
          <td>{i.tro}</td>
          <td>{i.bla}</td>
          <td>{i.blo}</td>
          <td>{i.bra}</td>
          <td>{i.bru}</td>
        </tr>
      )
    })
    return data
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="table-responsive">
        <table className="table table-sm table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>rank</th>
              <th>name</th>
              <th>rank</th>
              <th>name</th>
              <th>rank</th>
              <th>name</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {this.tableData}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      )
     }
```

Will look like:

[image]

Update using:

```
      <td>{i.tre || 'test TRE'}</td>
      <td>{i.tro || 'test TRO'}</td>
      <td>{i.bla || 'test BLA'}</td>
      <td>{i.blo || 'test BLO'}</td>
      <td>{i.bra || 'test BRA'}</td>
      <td>{i.bru || 'test BRU'}</td>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just concatenate your arrays, each element in `combined` will only have two properties, and the rest will be undefined. Instead, you'll want to merge the objects from each of the three arrays for each element in `combined`. Something like this should work:

```
const combined = [];
const maxLen = Math.max(arr1.length, arr2.length, arr3.length);
for (let i=0; i<maxLen; i++) {
  combined.push({...arr1[i], ...arr2[i], ...arr3[i]})
}
```

Or, if you use Lodash:

```
const combined = _.zipWith(arr1, arr2, arr3, (i1, i2, i3) => ({...i1, ...i2, ...i3}));
```

Comment: That works out better already! but what if one of the arrays gets more objects, then everything is limited to max 3 rows right? because there's basically 3 arrays as the length after the for loop.

Comment: The number of rows is equal to the length of the longest array, so if one of the arrays has more elements, there will be rows with empty fields. If you want to ensure filled rows, you could use `Math.min`, but then you might not include all your data.

Comment: Ah nevermind. I made the mistake myself. Your function worked fine if I extend one of the arrays. Indeed it gets adjusted to the longest array! thanks for your help. 

Do you have some tips how I can use this efficiently with huge data formats?

Comment: @pazta Not entirely sure what kind of tips you're looking for, probably better to formulate that in a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

The empty `td` tags might have been because object from `combined` doesn't have all the properties you are trying to access and `map` is returning `undefined` for them. Try the following and maybe you will be able to figure this out. If you see `Test ...` in your table, you will know which property is missing.

Hope it helps

```
tableData() {
    const combined = [...arr1, ...arr2, ...arr3];

    var data = combined.map((i, k) => {
      return (
        <tr key={k}>
          <td>{i.tre || "Test TRE" }</td>
          <td>{i.tro || "Test TRO" }</td>
          <td>{i.bla || "Test BLA" }</td>
          <td>{i.blo || "Test BLO" }</td>
          <td>{i.bra || "Test BRA" }</td>
          <td>{i.bru || "Test BRU" }</td>
        </tr>
      )
    })
    return data
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="table-responsive">
        <table className="table table-sm table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>rank</th>
              <th>name</th>
              <th>rank</th>
              <th>name</th>
              <th>rank</th>
              <th>name</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {this.tableData}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      )
     }
```

PS: It would be nice if you have provide more data for `combined`.

Comment: See update.. it just fills the empty td tags. but the arrays keep at the same position...